# Find String (or Char[]) in Textfile

Tags: c#, file-io

I got a Form that wants to have atleast one keyword, like *download*.

[image]

This is the Code to call my OpenFileDialog.
The Class is `Form1`

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initListView();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getallfiles.getSelectedFiles(this.listView1);
    }

    private void initListView()
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Filename", 210, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Size", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Match", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            seaching.matchResult(progressBar1, listView1, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Now I get the Multiselected Files and store them in the `filePaths` String[].
The Class is `getallfiles`

```
public static String[] filePaths;
    public static void getSelectedFiles(ListView listView)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openAllFiles = new OpenFileDialog();
        openAllFiles.Title = "Select all files you want to look for keywords";
        openAllFiles.Multiselect = true;
        openAllFiles.Filter = "(*.*)|*.*";
        if (openAllFiles.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filePaths = new string[openAllFiles.FileNames.Length];
            int count = 0;
            foreach (String file in openAllFiles.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    ListViewItem masterItem = new ListViewItem(new[] { Path.GetFileName(file), (Math.Round(((new FileInfo(file).Length) / 1024f), 3).ToString()) + " kb"});
                    listView.Items.Add(masterItem);
                    filePaths[count] = file;
                    count++;
                }
                catch (Exception f)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And now my Problemcode. I can filter if there is only the Keyword written, but if it's **downloading** and I set the Keyword to **download** my solutions stops working.
The Class is `searching`

```
public static void matchResult(ProgressBar progressBar, ListView listView, String key1, String key2)
    {
        progressBar.Maximum = getallfiles.filePaths.Length;
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        int count = 0;
        bool lockCount = false;
        String fileText;

        foreach (string file in getallfiles.filePaths)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(getallfiles.filePaths[count]))
            {
                while ((fileText = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key2) & !String.IsNullOrEmpty(key1))
                    {
                        if (fileText.Contains(key1.ToLower()) | fileText.Contains(key1.ToUpper()) | fileText.Contains(key1))
                        {
                            ListViewItem masterItem = new ListViewItem(new[] { Path.GetFileName(file), (Math.Round(((new FileInfo(file).Length) / 1024f), 3).ToString()) + " kb" });
                            listView.Items.Add(masterItem);
                            count++;
                            lockCount = true;
                            reader.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key2))
                    {
                        if (fileText.Contains(key1.ToLower()) | fileText.Contains(key2.ToLower()) | fileText.Contains(key1.ToUpper()) | fileText.Contains(key2.ToUpper()) | fileText.Contains(key1) | fileText.Contains(key2))
                        {
                            ListViewItem masterItem = new ListViewItem(new[] { Path.GetFileName(file), (Math.Round(((new FileInfo(file).Length) / 1024f), 3).ToString()) + " kb" });
                            listView.Items.Add(masterItem);
                            count++;
                            lockCount = true;
                            reader.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!lockCount)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My next Idea was to check for a Char[] but I'm not sure if this is efficient.
I'd let read *char* for *char* and store the current line in a char[] and compare if the char[] I'm looking for is in there.

Comment: Start using the correct logical operators && for logical AND and || for logical OR

Comment: Any reason not to use IndexOf ?

Comment: You should use case insensitive searches instead of searching the line multiple times (use a string comparison mode and indexOf). Also use ||, not | and why are you specifying getallfiles.filePaths[count] when you already have the loop variable (file)?